# .NET MAUI: Display a list of recent images in device

Tags: c#, maui

How do I get a list of recent images stored in the device?

This doesn't seem to work:

```
var directory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
            
var files = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.jpg|*.png", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

Comment: in the system gallery?  You will need to use the media API's, you can't just look at the file system

Answer (score 0):

your filter parameter is wrong: "*.jpg|*.png", the | char will not work as "or". 
You may use *Union()* to union enumerable of files with different extensions:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, "*.jpg", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)  
    .Union(Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, "*.png", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))  
    .ToList();
```